# How can one compute the Shapley value using Monte Carlo?

Tags: statistics, approximation, game-theory, approximation-theory, monte-carlo

I am working on an application for which I need to compute the [Shapley value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value#Formal_definition) (using the first formula from the definition section on the wiki). Since I am dealing with a large number of players (around 300), this clearly cannot be computed exactly, hence the need for some Monte Carlo-like algorithm. Here is what I am doing now:

```
while(epsilon < 5.0):
    for player in playerSet: 
        random_player_coalition = generateCoalitions(playerSet)

        # scaled, including the factor in front from the definition
       player_marginal_contribution = computeMarginalContribution(player, random_player_coalition)

        # list of marginal contributions for every coalition considered
        # of the form [marg1, marg2, marg3..., margN]
        player_shap_list += [player_marginal_contribution]

        prev_shap = sum(player_shap_list[:-1])
        curr_shap = sum(player_shap_list)

        delta_shap = abs(curr_shap - prev_shap)

        # percentage of change between steps
        epsilon = delta_shap * 100.0 / prev_shap
```

Is this the "proper" way to perform such an approximation? In reality, I have a threshold that says if `epsilon` is below a particular percentage for a number of steps, then consider convergence achieved.

My questions are two-fold:

1. Is this algorithm correct, in my assumption that it will reach some kind of convergence?
2. While running it, I noticed that it seems to be converging, as epsilon keeps decreasing with every step, however it's very very slow and takes a large number of samples. What are some tricks I can do to speed it up?

I am new to this area of Monte Carlo simulations, so I can use all the help I can get.

Comment: Do you know anything about the structure of the characteristic function? If it has some regularities, you could use some standard Monte Carlo techniques to reduce the variance by sampling predominantly from the largest contributions; but without knowing anything about the characteristic function, it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @joriki, yes, I am sampling more from smaller coalitions, the sampling probability having something like an exponential decay in terms of coalition size. The problem is, I am afraid that, if I am too aggressive with this condition, I will reach values which are far from the real ones.

Comment: Not if you do it properly. You can't just change the sampling distribution; you have to correct for that. If you do it properly, the expected value remains the same but the variance can be significantly reduced (in your parlance: the convergence can be speeded up). Take a look at [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling).